# How to change conditional formatting conditions depending on the active sheet? (OpenPyXl)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have a task to make conditional formatting of 3 sheets of Excel file.
But the conditions for the third file change.

The conditions are specified in the code. I cannot apply conditional formatting with different conditions for different sheets.

Here is my code that I am trying to run and I am getting an error:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('uk-sheet.xlsx')

# Trying to call 2 sheets of the workbook (2nd and 3rd sheets)
sheet = wb['Sponsored Products Campaigns', 'Sponsored Brands Campaigns']

# Generate Fill object
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='ee7811', end_color='ee7811', fill_type='solid')
fill_green = PatternFill(start_color='11ee66', end_color='11ee66', fill_type='solid')
fill_yellow = PatternFill(start_color='dfee11', end_color='dfee11', fill_type='solid')

font = Font(bold=False, color='000000')

cf_range = '$A$2:$AT$30000'

# Fill to formula dictionary
formula_dict = {
    fill_red: ['IF($AR2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)', 'IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2>3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_green: ['IF(AND($AR2>0.0001,$AR2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_yellow: ['IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2<4),TRUE,FALSE)']
}

# Apply changes to each worksheet
# Select each sheet from 1 to 3
for ws in wb.worksheets[1:3]:
    # Extract the fill and formula(s)
    for colour_fill, formulas in formula_dict.items():
        for formula in formulas:  # For each formula in the fill
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                          FormulaRule(
                                              formula=[formula],
                                              stopIfTrue=None,
                                              fill=colour_fill,
                                              font=font)
                                          )

# Trying to call 4th sheet of the workbook
sheet = wb['SP Search Term Report']

# Another cf_range
cf_range = '$A$2:$AA$3000'

#  Fill to formula dictionary for STR report
formula_dict = {
    fill_red: ['IF($Y2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)', 'IF(AND($Y2=0,$R2>=3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_green: ['IF(AND($Y2>0.0001,$Y2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_yellow: ['IF(AND($Y2=0,$R2<=2),TRUE,FALSE)']
}

# Apply changes to each worksheet
#  Select 4th sheet
for ws in wb.worksheets[3]:
    # Extract the fill and formula(s)
    for colour_fill, formulas in formula_dict.items():
        for formula in formulas:  # For each formula in the fill
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                          FormulaRule(
                                              formula=[formula],
                                              stopIfTrue=None,
                                              fill=colour_fill,
                                              font=font)
                                          )

# Save the modified workbook
wb.save('uk-sheet2.xlsx')
```

I am new to programming, so forgive me for my stupidity.

I read the whole tutorial, but it didn't make it any clearer to me how to do it. Please help me.

PS:Special thanks to user Moken for his help in past threads.

The error i get is "raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))" prnt.sc/EQfZCfSJmtkc –

So i need two conditional formattings for 3 sheets (1,2,3). And one of the formatting is need to be used to sheets by name 'Sponsored Products Campaigns' and 'Sponsored Brands Campaigns'. And the second formatting needs to be used to sheets by name 'SP Search Term Report' –

Comment: You should edit your question to add any additional details rather than add as comments to the question.

Comment: This is basically just a continuation of your first question. Would be better to update that.

Comment: ok, i did it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you can change your code to the below;

For the first two sheets `'Sponsored Products Campaigns', 'Sponsored Brands Campaigns'` you can just loop that list and assign `ws` to the sheet for each.
For the last sheet just directly assign `ws` to the name.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('uk-sheet.xlsx')

# Trying to call 2 sheets of the workbook (2nd and 3rd sheets)

# Generate Fill object
fill_red = PatternFill(start_color='ee7811', end_color='ee7811', fill_type='solid')
fill_green = PatternFill(start_color='11ee66', end_color='11ee66', fill_type='solid')
fill_yellow = PatternFill(start_color='dfee11', end_color='dfee11', fill_type='solid')

font = Font(bold=False, color='000000')

cf_range = '$A$2:$AT$30000'

# Fill to formula dictionary
formula_dict = {
    fill_red: ['IF($AR2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)', 'IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2>3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_green: ['IF(AND($AR2>0.0001,$AR2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_yellow: ['IF(AND($AR2=0,$AK2<4),TRUE,FALSE)']
}

# Apply changes to each worksheet
# Sheet list by name
sheets = ['Sponsored Products Campaigns', 'Sponsored Brands Campaigns']
for sheet in sheets:
    ### Select each sheet in the list to apply cf 
    ws = wb[sheet]
    # Extract the fill and formula(s)
    for colour_fill, formulas in formula_dict.items():
        for formula in formulas:  # For each formula in the fill
            ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                          FormulaRule(
                                              formula=[formula],
                                              stopIfTrue=None,
                                              fill=colour_fill,
                                              font=font)
                                          )

# Another cf_range
cf_range = '$A$2:$AA$3000'

#  Fill to formula dictionary for STR report
formula_dict = {
    fill_red: ['IF($Y2>0.309,TRUE,FALSE)', 'IF(AND($Y2=0,$R2>=3),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_green: ['IF(AND($Y2>0.0001,$Y2<=0.309),TRUE,FALSE)'],
    fill_yellow: ['IF(AND($Y2=0,$R2<=2),TRUE,FALSE)']
}

### Select 4th sheet by name 'SP Search Term Report'
ws = wb['SP Search Term Report']
### Extract the fill and formula(s)
for colour_fill, formulas in formula_dict.items():
    for formula in formulas:  # For each formula in the fill
        ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range,
                                      FormulaRule(
                                          formula=[formula],
                                          stopIfTrue=None,
                                          fill=colour_fill,
                                          font=font)
                                      )

# Save the modified workbook
wb.save('uk-sheet2.xlsx')
```